# Semi-automatically adding event handler methods

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading

**Background**: I am trying to implement a State Machine in C++14 as an exercise to get familiar with modern C++. To do so, I am implementing an Event handling mechanism, so that `State` objects can handle events either internally or by causing a transition to another State.

**Goal**: `State` defines a `virtual void handleEvent(const Event& e)` method and `State` subclasses should be able to define methods for a range of `Event` subclasses of their choice.

**Current Solution**: Using an `std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::function<void(const Event&)>>` and a method `template<class EventT> addHandler(std::function<void(const EventT&)>)` currently seems like the best option, but there's a lot of repetition as each actual handler method has to be added to the map in the constructor of the `State` subclass. This addition is quite wordy, as the actual handler needs to have `this` bound so that it can be passed around to the base class `addHandler` method.

**Question**: Is there a better solution, with less repetition and more automation of adding the event handlers?

Comment: I don't really understand your 'there's a lot of repetition as each actual handler method...' - could you add code where you set up these handlers (so we can see the repetitive bits that you are trying to get rid of).

Comment: The State subclasses both define a function `handleEvent` for an Event subclass and these functions had to be added to the `std::unordered_map` in the constructor. These additions included a lambda each to bind the function to `this`.
I don't have the exact code for this right now, but if you wish I can add it later. It was approximately the following: `_handlers[std::type_index(typeid(ConcreteEvent))] = [this] (const Event&e) {ConcreteState::handleConcreteEvent(this, static_cast<const ConcreteEvent&>(e));};` for each handler, in the constructor.

Comment: Here's a simplified version of my original code: http://pastebin.com/zzRMA0a8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is at least somewhat cleaner. Additional to the main `State` class, I defined a template class `IEventHandler<EventT>` with the function `virtual void handleEvent(const EventT&)`.

The `State` subclasses then also inherit from e.g. `IEventHandler<ConcreteEvent>` and the generic `handleEvent` function in `State` uses a `dynamic_cast` to see if `this` implements an event handler for the current event type. The cast version of `this` can then be used to handle the event.

There's still a bit of repetition here, but at least I don't have to register the handlers individually in the constructor as in my previous solution.